# Win8 app using C# as logic and html5/javascript as UI

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, microsoft-metro

So can i use C# as logic and html5/javascript as UI in Win8 app? Will my app pass market? 
Or i must use c#/xaml or html5/jsavascript only?

Comment: How about some research in the MSDN? I'm sure there you can find the app guideline. ;o)

Comment: And? there nothing in UX or UI part about c#/html5 mix. I see guideline for C#/XAML and HTML5/JavaScript only.

Comment: I meant some guildlines which contain the reasons for rejecting an app. ;o)

Answer (score 1):

Should not be a problem. Mix and match as you like... the content of the app is the important thing.